# Jenkinsでcheckstyleプラグインを実行するとパーサーエラーで結果が出力されない

Tags: xml, jenkins

現在、JenkinsにてAndroidプロジェクト用にCI環境を構築しているのですが、Checkstyleプラグインが動作せずに困っております。

### ■環境

OS:Windows 7 64bit/Ubuntu 16.04
Jenkins:2.53
Checkstyle Plug-in:3.47

### ■発生手順

①Android SDKを用意し、手動でGradleビルドが通る環境を構築(Windows/Linux共に)する。
②Jeninisのタスクでシェルの実行で、Gradleビルド追加。チェックスタイル実行を追加。
③ビルド実行。

以下の例外が発生し、Checkstyleが正常に完了しない。

== 例外 ==

```
モジュール : 例外により、ファイル /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LIBERTA-APP TEST/checkstyle-result.xml の処理に失敗しました:
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Input stream is not a Checkstyle file. at hudson.plugins.checkstyle.parser.CheckStyleParser.parse(CheckStyleParser.java:69)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractAnnotationParser.parse(AbstractAnnotationParser.java:54)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFile(FilesParser.java:323) 
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parseFiles(FilesParser.java:281) 
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.parserCollectionOfFiles(FilesParser.java:232) 
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:203) 
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.FilesParser.invoke(FilesParser.java:31) 
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:997) 
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975) 
at hudson.plugins.checkstyle.CheckStylePublisher.perform(CheckStylePublisher.java:78) 
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwarePublisher.perform(HealthAwarePublisher.java:68) 
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwareRecorder.perform(HealthAwareRecorder.java:295) 
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81) 
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20) 
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779) 
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720) 
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186) 
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665) 
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1760) 
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43) 
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

### ■確認状況

まず、例外の内容を確認しました。

[参考サイト][1]

https://github.com/jenkinsci/checkstyle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/checkstyle/parser/CheckStyleParser.java

```
module = (CheckStyle)digester.parse(new InputStreamReader(file, "UTF-8"));
if (module == null) {
    throw new SAXException("Input stream is not a Checkstyle file.");
}
```

例外は、上記のコード上の69行目で発生しているようでした。

UTF-8文字コード指定されており、チェックスタイルのxmlがS-JISとなっていたので、
ビルド前に以下のコマンドを追加し、変換を掛けたファイルを使用するようにしました。

```
# iconv -f SHIFT_JIS -t UTF-8 ./codingRule/JavaCodeStyle.xml -o ./codingRule/utf.xml
```

jenkinsのworkspaceを確認しましたが、確かに入力ファイルはUTF-8となっているのですが、状況が変わりません。

使用しているcheckstyle.xmlは、

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/google_style.html

で公開されているgoogleのJavaの規約なのですが、手元のAndorid Studio用のプラグインだと問題無く動作します。
試しに、以下の用に何も設定に含まない最小構成の入力ファイルを用意しましたが、結果変わらずです。

== 最小構成のXML ==

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name = "Checker">
</module>
```

１日試行錯誤しましたが、手詰まり状態です。
どなたか同じ状況に陥った事がある方、いらっしゃいましたらお力を貸して頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: 全くの当てずっぽうですが、UTF-8のXMLファイルにはBOMが付いてますか？もしついていればBOMを消してみるとどうでしょう。

Comment: 早々の確認ありがとうございます。UTF-8のXMLにはBOMはない事を確認しました。BOMの有無では無さそうです。

Comment: CheckStyle自体のバージョン(Checkstyle Plug-in:3.47ではなく、toolVersionで指定しているはず)を確認する必要がありそうです。使用しているcheckstyle.xmlに古いCheckStyleでは未対応のスタイルルールがあるのかもしれません。あと最小構成のXMLのようにDOCTYPE宣言まで削除してしまうとエラーになります。

Comment: すいません、理解できていないのですが、Jenkinsの管理＞プラグインの管理でみるとPlug-inはv3.47なのですが、別途、スタイルシート等にtoolVersionを指定して実行する必要があるという事でしょうか。

Comment: `build.gradle`などにCheckstyle Plug-inが使用するCheckstyleのバージョンが指定されているのかも...と考えたのですが、関係なかったようですね。

Answer (score 2):

もしかしたら
「ジョブの設定＞ビルド後の処理＞Checkstyle警告の集計＞集計するファイル」に
スタイル定義ファイル(checkstyle.xml)を設定していませんか？

もし、そのように設定してるなら…

ここは、スタイルをチェックした結果を集計するレポートファイルを指定する場所なので
gradle なら

```
build/reports/checkstyle/*.xml
```

とかになると思います。

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。集計ファイルにスタイル定義ファイルを設定するものだと思っておりました。試しに空のファイルを配置した処、"[CHECKSTYLE] 空のファイルなので、モジュール /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LIBERTA-APP TEST/checkstyle-result.xml のファイル  をスキップします。"とのエラー？が出力されました。もしかして、スタイルファイルを指定する場所は他にあったのでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。

GradleスクリプトからCheckstyleを実行させていなかった為の認識／設定不足でした。
<http://qiita.com/usamao/items/beadc631056d7815e788>
上記URLを元に、コマンドラインビルドするgradleスクリプトを作成し、jenkinsの実行コマンドに追加し、スクリプトの出力ファイルを集計ファイルに設定する事で解決しました。回答頂けた方々、ありがとうございます。